# How to inject repository to the interceptor in android architecture components?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, interceptor

I want to write Authentication Interceptor which is load access token from local db and add to the request header in android [architecture components boilerplate project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample).

AuthenticationInterceptor class:

```
class AuthenticationInterceptor: Interceptor, Authenticator {

   /*...*/

   override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        if (!request.url().encodedPath().equals("/login", ignoreCase = true)) {
           tokenRepository.getAccessToken().let {
              request = request?.newBuilder()
                    ?.addHeader("Authentication", "Bearer " + it)
                    ?.build()
           }
        }
        return chain.proceed(request)
   }

   override fun authenticate(route: Route, response: Response): Request? {
        /*...*/
   }
}
```

AppModule class where add interceptor to the OkHttpClient:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule {
    /*...*/

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTokenService(): TokenService {
       return Retrofit.Builder()       
           .client(
                   OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .addNetworkInterceptor(AuthenticationInterceptor()).build()
           )
           .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
           .build()
           .create(TokenService::class.java)
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

I try to add repository to the constructor, but then have to inject repository to the AppModule which cause build error

```
class AuthenticationInterceptor @Inject constructor(val tokenRepository: TokenRepository): Interceptor, Authenticator {
```

If I inject repository to the class field, then repository will be null

```
@Inject lateinit var tokenRepository: TokenRepository
```

**So my question how to inject repository to the interceptor?**

Comment: What build error do you get when trying to add the repository to AppModule?

Comment: #Onik - If I remember correctly then I got missing setter error message

Comment: On SO you should be specific.

Comment: #Onik - But setters should be auto generated in kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solve my problem:

- first: I use constructor injection on interceptor
- second: I dont create manually new instance instead add interceptor to the provider param:

  fun provideTokenService(authInterceptor: AuthenticationInterceptor): TokenService {
- third: the second point caused the circle dependency, because the repository use the service, so I dont use repository in interceptor instead use dao (or create another repository which not use service)